# How can I use RegEx to differentiate between screen resolutions?

Tags: regex, screen, range, resolution, qualtrics

I'm trying to create a RegEx expression that will match a numeric range from 0 to 600 so I can easily differentiate between a small mobile device and tablets/desktops. I'm using Qualtrics' survey software to do the rest - all I need is the RegEx expression.

However, I'm not 100% sure how Qualtrics takes in the data. I believe it takes it in the following format:

```
360x640
320x568
320x480
1920x1080
360x640
1280x800
320x568
1920x1080
360x640
1280x800
1920x1080
480x800
320x480
1280x800
1366x768
320x568
1280x800
```

Where I'm testing the FIRST number, e.g. the number before the 'x' character.

Here's some RegEx I've tried that did not work:

```
([0-9]{1,2}|[1-4][0-9]{2}|600)*x
```

That code recognizes numbers before the 'x', but it doesn't stop at 600 - it recognizes all numbers before the 'x' (e.g. from 000 to 9999).

How do I get the range I want? Please and thank you!

Note: I've tried using the RegEx number range generator [here](http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range), but it doesn't work for what I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there are width lower than 100, so you can use this pattern:

```
^([1-5][0-9]{2}|600)x
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do:

```
\b(?:600|[1-9]\d?|[1-5]\d{2})x
```

Where:

`\b` is a word boundary, it makes sure there're no digits before
`(?:  )` is a non capture group
`600` matches 600
`[1-9]\d?` matches number from 1 to 99
`[1-5]\d{2}` matches number from 100 to 599

Comment: I'd upvote yours since it was so well explained but I don't have a high enough reputation :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex but with `m` modifier if your input contains all those lines together:

```
^([0-5]\d{2}|600)x
```

[**Live demo**](http://regex101.com/r/lA8fG7/1)

Comment: @hwnd not actually, but her inputs are valid and she is just trying to take out desired ones.

Comment: Thanks! A friend gave me the following: ^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-7][0-9][0-9]|800)x([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-7][0-9][0-9]|800)$ -- Which is essentially the same but longer and also includes the 2nd number, which may be useful if I need it later on. Is there a way to simplify the above RegEx? Also, could you explain the "m" modifier to me? Thanks!